# Difference between GETDATE and SYSDATETIME

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the difference between `GETDATE` and `SYSDATETIME` ? Which one is commonly used?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The very first Google search result answers your question: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/10/sql-server-difference-between-getdate-and-sysdatetime/

Comment: I am thinking about the day that Google has not survived and Stackoverflow has, at that day this question is worth it  but seriously it's good to have a more complete SO even if the question and answer are present on other places, many people like me would rather to check SO first, because it loads faster and has a better community than most other websites. Don't you agree?

Comment: The very first Google search result brought me to this question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `GETDATE` the precision is till miliseconds and in case of `SYSDATETIME` the precision is till nanoseconds.

```
 SELECT GETDATE() fn_GetDate, SYSDATETIME() fn_SysDateTime
```

yields

```
 fn_GetDate                  fn_SysDateTime
 -----------------------     ---------------------------
 2018-07-20 11:07:26.403     2018-07-20 11:07:26.3980117
```

`DATETIME` is commonly used as higher precision corresponds to lower efficiency(marginally) in case of `SYSDATETIME`

Answer (score 0):

**SYSDATETIME** and **SYSUTCDATETIME** is more precise, i.e.. has more fractional seconds than GETDATE()

*GETDATE()* Is more generally used when you don't need that much precision

**Ex:**

- SELECT SYSDATETIME()   Results   2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381
- SELECT GETDATE()   Results       2007-04-30 13:10:02.047